# Migrating a service from Axis to Axis2 (Java) - Which MessageReceiver should I use?

Tags: java, xml, soap, web-services, apache-axis

I'm in the process migrating a service from Axis to Axis2 (Java).  The service responds to a simple SOAP request with a bit of "custom" XML in the body like the following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/secext">
   <UsernameToken Id="MyID">
    <Username>user</Username>
    <Password>pass</Password>
   </UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
  <dstm:ClientType xmlns:dstm="http://schemas.company.com/My_functions">Messaging.EWS</dstm:ClientType>
  <dstm:SessionScenario xmlns:dstm="http://schemas.company.com/My_functions">terminate</dstm:SessionScenario>
  <dstm:Organization xmlns:dstm="http://schemas.company.com/My_functions">*</dstm:Organization>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <tt:processBodyMessage xmlns:tt="http://core.ws.com"/>
  <GetZipCode_001 version="1.0" xmlns="http://schema.company.com/Company/1">
   <Get>
    <ActionExpression>getEntity</ActionExpression>
   </Get>
   <ZipCodeID>
    <Id>10003</Id>
   </ZipCodeID>
  </GetZipCode_001>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In Axis1, the service took an array of org.wc3.dom Elements as a parameter and processed them, e.g.

```
public Element[] processMessage(Element [] elems) { ... }
```

If I migrate the service to Axis2, I'm able to invoke it, but debugging reveals that the elems array is empty.  This is using RPCMessageReceivers in a mostly vanilla services.xml:

```
<service name="Connector">
 <Description>
  Connector Service ported to Axis2
 </Description>
 <messageReceivers>
  <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
  <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
 </messageReceivers>
 <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">com.ws.core.Service</parameter>
</service>
```

From what I've read about Axis2, it is generally not a good idea to have DOM objects in your service signature, so I tried using AXIOM OMElements:

```
public OMElement processMessage(OMElement e) { ... }
```

in conjunction with the RawXMLINOutMessageReceiver:

```
<service name="Connector">
 <Description>
  Connector Service ported to Axis2
 </Description>
 <operation name="processMessage">
      <messageReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOutMessageReceiver"/>
 </operation>
 <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">com.ws.core.Service</parameter>
</service>
```

This works a little better, but the only thing that gets passed into "e" is the first element of the SOAP body.

If I try to change the method signature to accept an array of OMElements:

```
public OMElement processMessage(OMElement[] e) { ... }
```

I get an Axis2 fault complaining that there is no method that implements the required method signature.

I have also tried using an array of OMElements with RPCMessageReceiver, but this results in an empty array being passed in.

**Can anyone offer advice about what sort of receiver/method signature combination I can use to get access to all XML elements in the body of the SOAP request?**  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real issue here was that the Axis1 service was processing valid DOM, but malformed SOAP requests. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985060.aspx, "A root element is a distinguished element that is an immediate descendant of either the soap:Body or soap:Header element. **soap: Body has exactly one root element**, which represents the call, response, or fault object." You can see that the SOAP body had multiple root elements, which does not adhere to the standard:

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <tt:processBodyMessage xmlns:tt="http://core.ws.com"/>
  <GetZipCode_001 version="1.0" xmlns="http://schema.company.com/Company/1">
   ...
  </GetZipCode_001>
 </soapenv:Body>
```

In the end, I chose to go with the RAWXMLINOutMessageReceiver and its standard service entry signature:

```
public OMElement processMessage(OMElement e) { ... }
```

If you need access to other pieces of the SOAP envelope inside this method, you can access them via the MessageContext, e.g.

```
SOAPEnvelope envelope = MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext().getEnvelope();
SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();
```